# VS2013 or VS2015 shows "unspecified error"

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, visual-studio-2015

When I open my worked solution (after merge from other branch) VS2013 shows error message "unspecified error" and I cannot close the window (the error's dialog jumps each time when I close it).
VS2012 opens the solution without error messages.
I suspect issue related to TFS configuration.
How can I found actual reason of the error?

[image]

Comment: I changed permissions on the folder & rebooted - this fixed it for me.

Comment: This is a bug in 2017 also.  Can't get a worse un-descriptive error then this one.

Comment: @niico permissions has nothing to do with this issue for me.  I have the entire directory and sub directories with all the code as full control for everyone,

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I still don't understand the actual reason for this error, but I found a workaround.

According to "Change source control" window (VS) solution file (.sln) not connected to TFS
[image]

When I connected the solution to TFS in VS2012 (with the help of [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0eh3790h(v=vs.90).aspx)), VS2013 opened the solution too without error message.

Comment: I had this problem when I connected to the TFS server with the full domain name instead of just the hostname, i.e. tfsServer => tfsServer.example.com.

Comment: @constructor this definitely was not my issue.  Every single project of the set of 34 were managed properly.

Answer (score 36):

I have searched a lot about its root cause but couldn't found any concrete information.

For me,

- **Deleting the solution's .suo file.**

resolve this problem.

Comment: Note that VS2015 might create hidden ".vs" sub-directory in the solutions folder that contains .suo files. I needed to delete that too. Deleting the .suo files next to the .sln files was not enough.

Comment: It's always `.suo`'s fault.

Comment: Unfortunately this works the first time.  Then the problem comes back.  For this solution to work I'd have to delete the files every time I reload the project.

Comment: @Mike you can investigate further why your solution file is corrupting again. I would suggest after cleaning the .suo file, clean you build and rebuild whole solution again.

Answer (score 7):

Found a solution at this [address](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d2312f94-a547-4bda-abae-e8c0fe407c9e/unspecified-error-on-open-solution-in-visual-studio-2012?forum=csharpide):

1. Go at  File -> Source Control -> Advanced -> Change Source Control
2. Select your projects and unbind them
3. Rebind them.

The problem should be solved.

Comment: your suggestion is same as what "answer" is suggesting.

Comment: @batmaci But he points out where to find "Change Source Control".

Comment: The accepted answer doesn't suggest unbinding and re-binding, which is what I had to do. This is a good additional answer.

Comment: I had to unbind all of my projects and then rebind as this answer suggests. Tip: it seems that you can't multi-select projects and bind/unbind the entire group. If you have a lot of projects you can select the first project and then click the unbind button repeatedly. To bind again, select the *bottom* project and click the bind button repeatedly.

Answer (score 1):

I have removed and recreated new workspace for the project and its works for me

Comment: This appears to have worked for me but I dont know if it's a perm fix or until the next time I go in.  The weird thing is this issue has creeped into other solutions.

Answer (score 1):

This always works for me 100% of the time.

1. Make sure your solution is closed.
2. Open your solution.
3. As ***QUICKLY
   AS YOU CAN*** press Ctrl-Shift-B.

Your solution will build and the error message will disappear. When it reappears do the same thing again.

Answer (score -1):

May be URL of TFS server is mentioned wrongly in solution file.