# Unspecified error received when adding VS2019 project to TFS2018

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2019

Environment:
Windows 10 2004
Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 16.7.6
TFS 2018.2 on Windows 2019 Server

I have a VS 2019 solution containing 14 C# projects. All of the projects are in TFS. For some reason one project is not showing in Solution Explorer as being in TFS (no lock icon). At one time it did show, sometime in the last month the lock disappeared. If I use Source Control Explorer in VS2019, I can navigate to the project and perform TDS operations on it.

If right click on the project on go to Source Control -> Add to Source Control I get an error window that simply says "Unspecified Error". Is there someplace I can look to find the error?

If there is any additional information I can provide, please let me know.

Thank you,
Eric

Comment: If you go to the "Output" tab in VS2019, and in the "Show output from:" dropdown select "Source Control - Team Foundation", and retry the operation, does that give any additional detail about the error?

Comment: Also, have a look at the answers to this question :https://stackoverflow.com/q/28926888/493557

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, G-P The link at [VS2013 or VS2015 shows "unspecified error"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28926888/493557) fixed the issue. I should have widened my search to older versions. Another life lesson.

Thanks again,
Eric.